# why I am getting `useCart/addItem Error: Product Type undefined not supported in add to cart yet` error in `vue storefront`?

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, vue-storefront

```
script>
import {ref} from '@nuxtjs/composition-api';
import {useProduct, useCart} from '~/composables';
import {SfImage, SfTile, SfHeading, SfPrice, SfSelect, SfAddToCart} from '@storefront-ui/vue';
import productGetters from '~/modules/catalog/product/getters/productGetters';

export default {
  components: {
    SfTile,
    SfImage,
    SfHeading,
    SfPrice,
    SfSelect,
    SfAddToCart
  },
  setup() {
    const searchHandler = ref('');
    const product = ref([]);
    const prodDetail = ref([])
    const quantity = ref('')
    const {
      getProductList,
      getProductDetails,
    } = useProduct();
    const {
      addItem,
      load,
      isInCart,
      error
    } = useCart()
    const buttonHandler = async () => {
      const productList = await getProductList(
        {
          filter: {
            sku: {
              eq: searchHandler.value.toString()
            }
          }
        }
      )
      const productDetail = await getProductDetails(
        {
          filter: {
            sku: {
              eq: searchHandler.value.toString()
            }
          }
        }
      )
      prodDetail.value = productDetail.items
      product.value = productList.items

      console.log(product.value[0], 'product list')
      console.log(prodDetail.value[0], 'product detail')
    }
// add to cart handler
    const addToCartHandler = async () => {
      const productValue = await addItem({
        product: prodDetail.value,
        quantity:quantity.value
      })
      console.log(error,"error in composable")
      console.log(productValue,'product added to the cart')
      console.log(quantity, 'quantity of the product')
    }
    // get product handler
    const productHandler = async () => {
      await load
      console.log(isInCart(),"cart values")
    }
    return {
      searchHandler,
      product,
      productGetters,
      buttonHandler,
      prodDetail,
      addToCartHandler,
      SfImage,
      SfTile,
      SfHeading,
      SfPrice,
      SfSelect,
      SfAddToCart,
      getProductDetails,
      getProductList,
      quantity,
      productHandler
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

I am trying to implement `add to cart` functionality here, but getting `useCart/addItem Error:

```
 Product Type undefined not supported in add to cart yet`
```

The error I really don't know what is happening here. I'm also getting undefined in the console. I am adding simple products, but i think the error is about type, but don't know how to resolve this issue.

Comment: What is `addItem` in your useCart composable? We can't see that code, but as a guess I'd assume you're missing a property of 'product type' that you need to pass to it along with the 'product' and 'quantity'

Comment: yes that is my coposable

Comment: Hi, yes I know. I'm asking what the code is for `addItem`, as that's likely where the solution is.